# Android - Internal or external storage?... context.getFilesDir() or context.getExternalFilesDir()?

Tags: android, file, local-storage, shared-memory

I've read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) article, but I'm not sure where is the best place to store the image data from my app.

My app contains a products database, and when a product is viewed, the image for that product is downloaded from the server and needs to be stored locally.

Most advice seems to be use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but very few posts seem to recommend `context.getExternalFilesDir()` - despite it possibly being more appropriate for many types of apps (and not requiring manifest permissions since KitKat).

Anyway, the problem with both these two external storage solutions is that they generally require the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission - which is likely to put off a lot of my prospective users.

So I today discovered `context.getFilesDir()` for internal storage - which ***seems*** ideal for my applications as it does not appear to require a manifest permission and if the user uninstalls my app then all the content will get cleaned up (plus, the content my app stores there will not be publicly visible - which I suppose is bonus).

The aforementioned Android documentation does not warn against using `context.getFilesDir()`, so I am wondering what the drawbacks are? Clogging up the internal storage with downloaded data is the only one I can think of - but if it is the case that most apps are writing to external storage, then if my app also writing external storage then isn't that more likely to clog things up?

So, to summarise, I want to store downloaded images on the device, really want to avoid adding manifest permissions, would prefer other apps being unable to access my data, but want to solve this the 'right' way - so does using internal storage / `context.getFilesDir()` fit the bill or am I missing something??

Comment: its called preference..lol.. use what might suit you better. there is also internal-external memory(not sd card) public folder..(`Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`,`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`) you could use that too, devices without these directory is goin to automatically store on the sd card..but if you choose internal it goes straight to internal..

Comment: In "old" devices (think 2 years ago) internal storage was very small, and most devices had much bigger external storage (SD cards).

Comment: It's not just about what suits me, but what also suits the user and their device. The fact that the Android documentation does not allude to internal/external storage constraints is what is making me ask on here if it really is (still) such an issue?

Comment: ...and that's presuming Google have updated their documentation in the past two years! :)

Comment: Many current devices don't even have SD card slots, so "external" storage is an emulated filesystem.  You don't need to share your images between applications, so there's little value in using "external" storage.  Use the "internal" app storage.